# Parsing Json data giving ClassCastException

Tags: java, json, api, parsing

I am currently using the following JSON parser but keep getting the error Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject. How can I fix this, it has worked many times before.

```
ublic List<String> handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
                throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            String JSONResponse = new BasicResponseHandler()
                    .handleResponse(response);

            try {

                // Get top-level JSON Object - a Map
                JSONObject responseObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(
                        JSONResponse).nextValue(); //Problem Line



                JSONObject item1 = responseObject.getJSONObject("searchResult");
                // Extract value of "Item" key -- a List
                JSONArray items = item1
                        .getJSONArray("Item");
```

Below is what I'm looking to parse

```
{
"findItemsAdvancedResponse":[
    {
        "ack":[
            "Success"
        ],
        "version":[
            "1.13.0"
        ],
        "timestamp":[
            "2015-02-24T18:43:51.778Z"
        ],
        "searchResult":[
            {
                "@count":"100",
                "item":[
                    {
                        "itemId":[
                            "381098176861"
                        ],
                        "title":[
                            " Tokyo Laundry Women's Kenzie Sweatpants - Eclipse Blue - TP1"
                        ],
                        "globalId":[
                            "EBAY-GB"
                        ],
                        "subtitle":[
                            "FREE UK DELIVERY | DISPATCHED WITHIN 1 WORKING DAY"
                        ],
                        "primaryCategory":[
                            {
                                "categoryId":[
                                    "137085"
                                ],
                                "categoryName":[
                                    "Activewear"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "secondaryCategory":[
                            {
                                "categoryId":[
                                    "155226"
                                ],
                                "categoryName":[
                                    "Hoodies & Sweats"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "galleryURL":[
                            "http:\/\/thumbs2.ebaystatic.com\/pict\/3810981768614040_1.jpg"
                        ],
                        "viewItemURL":[
                            "http:\/\/www.ebay.co.uk\/itm\/Tokyo-Laundry-Womens-Kenzie-Sweatpants-Eclipse-Blue-TP1-\/381098176861?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&var="
                        ],
                        "paymentMethod":[
                            "PayPal"
                        ],
                        "autoPay":[
                            "true"
                        ],
                        "location":[
                            "United Kingdom"
                        ],
                        "country":[
                            "GB"
                        ],
                        "shippingInfo":[
                            {
                                "shippingServiceCost":[
                                    {
                                        "@currencyId":"GBP",
                                        "__value__":"0.0"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "shippingType":[
                                    "Free"
                                ],
                                "shipToLocations":[
                                    "AU",
                                    "Europe"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "sellingStatus":[
                            {
                                "currentPrice":[
                                    {
                                        "@currencyId":"GBP",
                                        "__value__":"14.99"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "convertedCurrentPrice":[
                                    {
                                        "@currencyId":"GBP",
                                        "__value__":"14.99"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "sellingState":[
                                    "Active"
                                ],
                                "timeLeft":[
                                    "P25DT14H10M23S"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "listingInfo":[
                            {
                                "bestOfferEnabled":[
                                    "false"
                                ],
                                "buyItNowAvailable":[
                                    "false"
                                ],
                                "startTime":[
                                    "2014-12-22T08:49:14.000Z"
                                ],
                                "endTime":[
                                    "2015-03-22T08:54:14.000Z"
                                ],
                                "listingType":[
                                    "FixedPrice"
                                ],
                                "gift":[
                                    "false"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "galleryPlusPictureURL":[
                            "http:\/\/galleryplus.ebayimg.com\/ws\/web\/381098176861_1_1_1.jpg"
                        ],
                        "condition":[
                            {
                                "conditionId":[
                                    "1000"
                                ],
                                "conditionDisplayName":[
                                    "New with tags"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "isMultiVariationListing":[
                            "true"
                        ],
                        "topRatedListing":[
                            "false"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "itemId":[
                            "131321072184"
                        ],
                        "title":[
                            "Brave Soul Women's Dallas Parka - Mulberry - DD6 - Size 8-16"
                        ],
                        "globalId":[
                            "EBAY-GB"
                        ],
                        "subtitle":[
                            "FREE UK DELIVERY | DISPATCHED WITHIN 1 WORKING DAY"
                        ],
                        "primaryCategory":[
                            {
                                "categoryId":[
                                    "137085"
                                ],
                                "categoryName":[
                                    "Activewear"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "secondaryCategory":[
                            {
                                "categoryId":[
                                    "63862"
                                ],
                                "categoryName":[
                                    "Coats & Jackets"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "galleryURL":[
                            "http:\/\/thumbs1.ebaystatic.com\/pict\/1313210721844040_3.jpg"
                        ],
                        "viewItemURL":[
                            "http:\/\/www.ebay.co.uk\/itm\/Brave-Soul-Womens-Dallas-Parka-Mulberry-DD6-Size-8-16-\/131321072184?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&var="
                        ],
                        "paymentMethod":[
                            "PayPal"
                        ],
                        "autoPay":[
                            "true"
                        ],
                        "location":[
                            "United Kingdom"
                        ],
                        "country":[
                            "GB"
                        ],
                        "shippingInfo":[
                            {
                                "shippingServiceCost":[
                                    {
                                        "@currencyId":"GBP",
                                        "__value__":"0.0"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "shippingType":[
                                    "Free"
                                ],
                                "shipToLocations":[
                                    "AU",
                                    "Europe"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "sellingStatus":[
                            {
                                "currentPrice":[
                                    {
                                        "@currencyId":"GBP",
                                        "__value__":"19.99"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "convertedCurrentPrice":[
                                    {
                                        "@currencyId":"GBP",
                                        "__value__":"19.99"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "sellingState":[
                                    "Active"
                                ],
                                "timeLeft":[
                                    "P15DT14H57M21S"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "listingInfo":[
                            {
                                "bestOfferEnabled":[
                                    "false"
                                ],
                                "buyItNowAvailable":[
                                    "false"
                                ],
                                "startTime":[
                                    "2014-10-13T09:36:12.000Z"
                                ],
                                "endTime":[
                                    "2015-03-12T09:41:12.000Z"
                                ],
                                "listingType":[
                                    "FixedPrice"
                                ],
                                "gift":[
                                    "false"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "galleryPlusPictureURL":[
                            "http:\/\/galleryplus.ebayimg.com\/ws\/web\/131321072184_1_5_1.jpg"
                        ],
                        "condition":[
                            {
                                "conditionId":[
                                    "1000"
                                ],
                                "conditionDisplayName":[
                                    "New with tags"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "isMultiVariationListing":[
                            "true"
                        ],
                        "topRatedListing":[
                            "false"
                        ]
                    },
```

Comment: Looking at http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONTokener.html#nextValue() it looks like it is perfectly valid that `nextValue()` will return a `String`. Maybe your response is not in the format you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need a `JSONTokener`? This is much easier:

```
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(JSONResponse);
JSONArray main = responseObject.getJSONArray("findItemsAdvancedResponse");
JSONObject result = main.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("searchResult").getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray items = result.getJSONArray("item");
```

Comment: Using this helps how? Getting a mismatch exception

Comment: I am using this method in my app and it is working fine. Can you please post your new source code and the exact error message?

Comment: I have updated my answer. The code is tested with your JSON, working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your nextValue() method must be returning a String, which you are then trying to cast to a JSONObject.  I would start by splitting the statement up into smaller statements to help isolate the issue. You are instantiating a new object, calling a method on it, and type casting all on the same line.  That makes code harder to debug.

```
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(JSONResponse);
Object obj = tokener.nextValue();

if(obj.getClass().equals(JSONObject.class))
{
    JSONObject responseObject = (JSONObject)obj;
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Not a JSONObject");
}
```